# Http serialisation and deserialization

Tags: http, serialization, http-headers, deserialization, mime-types

How does do http libraries know which serializer or deserializer is to be used for a request or response

Does http have its own serializer/ deserializer defined for each of MIME type?

Which serialisation/deserialization library does http use for JSON and protobuf Mime types ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the service framework you're using. In the [Java EE JAX-RS framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services), classes known as [entity providers](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jax-rs/providers.html) are responsible for reading from and writing to services. These entity providers implement the [MessageBodyReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) or [MessageBodyWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) interfaces which perform the data manipulation. The `MessageBodyReader` uses the [`Consumes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) annotation to specify what mime types it reads. Similarly, a `MessageBodyWriter` uses the [`Produces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotation to specify what mime types it writes. The framework selects the correct entity provider based on the specified mime type of the service call.

There are many implementations available. For instance, you could use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for JSON conversion or the [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) library.